# How to convert Json to Java for making POST request using rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I would like to post below request using the below payload and looking for a better way to do this rather than posting it this way with escaping characters.

"{\n" +        "\t\"name\": \"nameValue\",\n" +        "\t\"age\": \"ageValue\",\n" +        "\t\"sex\": \"sexValue\",\n" +        "\t\"mobile\": \"mobileVal-uk\",\n" +        "\t\"codes\": [\n" +        "\t\t\"8567\"\n" +        "\t]\n" +        "}";

I would like using something like below eg arraylist, jsonObject, hashmap or jsonrray.

```
@Test
public void studentDetails() {    
RestAssured.baseURI = "  http://localhost:3000";    
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();    
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();    
array.put(Integer.parseInt("codes"), "8567");    
JSONObject arrayItem = new JSONObject();    
arrayItem.put("name", "nameValue");    
arrayItem.put("age", "ageValue");    
arrayItem.put("sex", "sexValue");    
arrayItem.put("mobile", "mobileVal");    
mainObject.put(String.valueOf(array), arrayItem);
given()            
  .body(mainObject.toString())            
  .when() 
  .post("/posts")            
  .then()
  .assertThat()
  .statusCode(200)
  .contentType(ContentType.JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). You can create a POJO that will represent your JSON object which will allow you to go between JSON and Java objects easily. It will save you a lot of trouble and you won't have to worry about all of that awful formatting :)

Here is a more in depth tutorial - https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/

Comment: I have read about POJO, but don’t want to it as it’s only a small data am posting. POJO is good for large sets of data. Where the confusion is for is how to handle the “codes”: [ 
“8567”
] and put it in an array and add it to json objects.

Comment: Can someone please help with the above.

Comment: @user9790882 If you don't want to use POJO you can use JSON.simple library. https://mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Answer (score 0):

Goto http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and create POJOs and use them to send in request and response in object.